# Automatically give database ownership to a login group that creates a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a sysadmin on one of our SQL servers.

We have a Login named [COMPANY\Test_User], that is currently given the 'public' server role. We want any user within this login to be able to create their own databases and then automatically then everyone within [COMPANY\Test_User] has ownership of this database (db_owner). This is so they can create, drop, backup and restore their own databases without having to ask me to grant permissions to do so.

Is there a level of access I can grant to that Login, without giving them access to all the other databases?

In summary, I want [COMPANY\Test_User] to be automatically be added to role db_owner for any database created through the [COMPANY\Test_User] Login.

i.e. [COMPANY\Test_User] can run the following code on a database created by  [COMPANY\Test_User], but cannot alter the roles on any other database.

```
USE [Test_Database]
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [COMPANY\Test_User]
```

Update:
The issue here is that Person A using login [COMPANY\Test_User] creates a database, and then Person B using login [COMPANY\Test_User] tries to drop the same database and doesn't have permissions to do so - and I don't know why. And then they don't have permissions to be able to run the ALTER ROLE command.

Comment: Is `[COMPANY\Test_User]` a AD Group then? Whenever a login creates a database, they will automatically be the owner, so I'm not really sure what the problem is here.

Comment: FYI `db_owner` != "Owner of the database"

Comment: I have to say that allowing the public role privilege to create a database is scary as hell. I would create a new role that is not the public role that has these privileges.

Comment: @Larnu Yes it is. That is what I thought too. But a Person A using login [COMPANY\Test_User] creates a database, and then Person B using login [COMPANY\Test_User] tries to drop the same database and doesn't have permissions to do so.

Comment: So is `[COMPANY\Test_User]` a Login? If so, then I can't see why the other (AD) user would not be able to drop it if `[COMPANY\Test_User]` is the owner (as the other User will have the permissions of the `[COMPANY\Test_User]` SQL Login), unless there is an explicit deny somewhere. But like @SeanLange said, the `public` server role should not be able to create a database. You should be giving the `[COMPANY\Test_User]` login that permission.

Comment: @Larnu So under Security > Logins, there is a `[COMPANY\Test_User]`. If I look at the properties for the database Person A created, under permissions there is only `[COMPANY\Test_User]` as expected. I assume since Person A created the db, they are now owner of it? This Person A can then backup, restore and delete the database, but nobody else within Login  `[COMPANY\Test_User]` can do so... and it's this I can't figure out.